# Program not appearing in Uninstall list

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I need to uninstall Unity as I have run out of storage and the program is very large. When I search for it on Windows 10, there is an uninstall button which takes me to the control panel with a list of programs to uninstall, but the program isn't on the list. I have also searched through Apps & Features and settings, but it does not appear there either. I have used `wmic` in command line for a list of programs with `product get name` and it is still not listed. What can I do to uninstall it?

Comment: One possible fix for this issue is to install the program again to create an uninstall entry

Comment: You can uninstall Unity through Unity Hub

Answer (score 0):

Summary of
[How to Uninstall Unity on Windows](https://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-Unity-on-Windows) :

- Run *Start > Unity Hub*
- Click the Installs tab
- Click the three vertical dots on your Unity install, select Uninstall
  and confirm
- To quit Unity Hub, click its taskbar icon and select "Quit Unity Hub"
- Run *Windows Settings > Apps*
- Click "Unity Hub" on the right
- Click Uninstall and confirm
- Do the same to the "Unity Hub Uninstall utility"
- Click "Finish" to close the installer.